# Lookup column agains list with more than 5000 posts

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, large-lists

I am new to SP online.

This is about a lookup column that displays data from another list which is currently exceeds the 5000 items limit?

Any easy solution as I dont have much programming experience.

Comment: What exactly the problem you are facing? please add some more details to your question.

Comment: We have a subscriber database of 5697 .When a subscriber calls in , I need the operator to select the relevant subscriber sand log an issue against that subscriber .   This is done via an an issue list ,with a lookup to the subscriber database ?

Comment: Try to index the columns or columns in the parent list. Surprisingly, this is working for us now, and I heard from Microsoft that they do not support it.

Answer (score 2):

This will never work, you are pretty much out of luck.

I have been down this road and still travelling along it. Once SharePoint hits 5k anything, it falls over in almost every sense of the word.

SharePoint Online is not meant for enterprise use, period.

Answer (score 0):

You can [add an index](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-an-index-to-a-sharepoint-column-f3f00554-b7dc-44d1-a2ed-d477eac463b0) manually from List Settings in the settings menu > Indexed Columns.

More information, you can refer to:
[Manage large lists and libraries in SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-sharepoint-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59)

Comment: I have added an index .. .but still there is an issue ?

Comment: @kally_MSFT  how would adding an index help with a lookup field threshold?

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a lookup column over a list that exceds the treshold limit. On SharePoint Online you can't modify it, and this threshold is setted to 5000 elements.